# Position images on top of each other with some precision in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to position two images on top of each other with some level of precison.

The problem is, the top image (the circle) goes all over the place.

Both images are in a responsive grid and the base image is supposed to be centered all the time.

Let's say that, for example, I'm trying to target the hip.
[image]

Whenever I shrink the page, the right image goes below (which is exactly what I want), while the circle goes somewhere else (in this case, the hand).[image]

Here's my code:

```css
/* No-margins Class Rules */

.row.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.row.no-gutters>[class^="col-"],
.row.no-gutters>[class*=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}


/* Centers content */

.centered-img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.img-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- global canvas -->
    <div class="row no-gutters">

      <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="centered-img">

          <img src="./images/fssFront.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
          <img src="./images/circle.png" class="test" alt="Responsive image">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="centered-img">
          <img src="./images/fssBack.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- global canvas -->
</body>

</html>
```

How can I position the red circle on top of the man so it always stays on the same place whenever I stretch or shrink the page?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried playing with 
    position: relative;
for your circle?

Comment: Also, the class .img-container {} is never used in your html. Not sure if you're aware of that.

Comment: I am. That's part of my testing. But thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your two images are using different reference points to determine their location. Additionally, for it to be responsive you need everything in percentages.

The first part. By setting `position:absolute` on your circle, you're changing it's reference point to the next container up that has `position:relative` or `position:absolute` set on it. In your case there are none, so it's using the page, the entire document, as its reference point. If the circle has a reference point of the page, and the image has a reference point of its parent, when you resize, they are going to anchor to different points and you'll never get them lined up.

Additionally, since you want it to be responsive, all of your measurements will need to be in %. `left:100px` is set on your circle, which won't work when you start to resize. You need to either get the exact location with the `transform` property, or change your `left` property to a percentage.

Comment: Thanks. Your feedback helped a lot. It's pretty obvious, now that I think about it. I'm just not used to html and css.